# Java to Control a Windows Server

Tags: java, windows, ssh, remote-desktop, windows-shell

As we know Java can send SSH command to a Linux server by jsch or sshj. Is it possible to do same thing to a Windows server, by remote desktop protocol (on port 3389) or other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I guess the issue is less about Java itself but about the choice of remote control in the first place.

`ssh` is a textual protocol, connecting a terminal on the client to a login session / shell on the server so that the shell will use the terminal on the client for its default `stdin` / `stdout` / `stderr`. Unless you use `ssh -X`, in which case `ssh` will in addition to that establish a tunnel for the X-protocol. This means that `ssh` is primarily a means of textual remote control.

As far as I am aware, RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol is primarily a means of graphical remote control, making automation really difficult as compared to textual remote control.

So, it pretty much depends on whether you want textual / command control or graphical control, and they are very very different from each other.

The best and most convenient way known to me to turn a Windows machine into something that can be remote controlled *textually* in a controlled and reasonably fashion, mostly for the purposes of automation, is to install *Cygwin with `sshd`* and setup `sshd` as a service. Then you can use the same client libraries regardless of whether your server is running on Linux / UNIX / Mac OS X or Windows.

`telnet` and `rlogin` would also be possible, but I would not recommend those because of their lack of encryption - everyone with access to the network could obtain the login credentials by simple eavesdropping.

If you want to use graphical remote control, you could use *RDP* or *X11*, to name just two. You can get *X11* running on Windows by setting up Cygwin `xdm` running as a service on the Windows machine to use XDMCP - X Display Manager Control Protocol. There are also services available for Linux that provide *RDP*, in case you choose *RDP* and want the same protocol for all servers.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Proper Java RDP](http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/) or [Lixia java RDP](https://code.google.com/p/lixia-javardp/) for use in the place of [JSCH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/) or [SSHJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj)

NB : The code supports Windows Server 2008 and has not been tested with Windows Server 2012

Comment: All my servers to control are Windows XP or Server 2003 so there is no "Windows Terminal Services" at all :-(